# Emploi de « de » dans « afin que soit décidé de cette réponse »

Tags: grammaire, sens

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer l'emploi de « de » dans la dernière phrase ? Il me semble que « de » pourrait être supprimé ici.

Voici le [texte](https://unesdoc.unesco.org/ark:/48223/pf0000385891) :

> Cette Conférence qui s’ouvre va se prononcer sur une question à la fois simple et éminemment stratégique.
>
> Une question qu’il a été difficile de faire arriver jusqu’à vous, et qui se pose probablement dans une fenêtre de circonstances unique.
>
> Alors que les États-Unis se sont mobilisés pour disposer enfin des moyens juridiques, administratifs, politiques et financiers d’un plein retour au sein de notre Organisation en juillet 2023, quelle réponse la communauté de 193 États membres qui la composent souhaite-t-elle leur apporter ?
>
> Vous avez été 139 États à me demander d’organiser cette session extraordinaire avant juillet, afin que soit décidé de cette réponse.

Comment: Ces sont des paroles prononcées probablement sans texte écrit. Toutes les personnes qui parlent font toujours des petits écarts de cette nature.

Comment: Il y a aussi ceux qui veulent écrire avec une certaine pompe administrative pour faire plus "officiel" ...

Comment: Le document écrit contient bien ce « de » mais il n'est pas certain qu'Audrey Azoulay l'a prononcé au moment où elle a lu son discours.

Comment: Dans le contexte d'une réunion, d'une assemblée, on emploie plutôt "décider d'une réponse" que "décider une réponse". La phrase passive de la question est un cas très particulier mais en général, ce "de" n'a rien de superflu. Cf https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/decider II.A.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avec le passif, la tournure n'est pas très heureuse. "Décider de qqch" existe bien, mais dans cette tournure passive, on a l'impression qu'il manque un sujet, alors que le sujet logique, ce dont on parle, est évidemment la "réponse", qui est utilisé comme complément, d'où l'impression que la phrase est un peu bancale.

J'aurais écrit *afin qu'une réponse soit décidée* ou bien *afin que nous décidions d'une réponse*.

Une autre possibilité, suggérée par Graffito (merci!): *afin qu'il soit décidé de cette réponse*.

Comment: @Graffito Oui, merci de cet ajout. J'ai +1 ton commentaire. Si tu veux, je peux l'ajouter à ma réponse.

Comment: Pourriez-vous m'expliquer la syntaxe de la dernière possibilité suggérée par Graffito ? J'arrive pas à la comprendre...

Comment: @AlexW Le verbe, c'est _décider_, ici utilisé avec la préposition _de_ qui introduit ce que l'on doit décider. Comme _réponse_ est complément du verbe ici, on a besoin d'un sujet, et on utilise un _il_ impersonnel par défaut. Je pense que cet emploi impersonnel du pronom _il_ peut être généralisé, mais _il_ ne me vient pas d'autre exemple à l'esprit. _Il_ faudrait que j'y réfléchisse.

Comment: @Frank Merci, j'ai bien compris ! J'avais pas de problème avec le pronom impersonnel et je sais bien utiliser « il est certain que » « il semble », etc. Je crois que c'est le passif et le verbe intransitif ici qu'on voit rarement qui me paraissent bizarre.

Comment: @AlexW Oui, ce passif est un peu "ampoulé" pour moi. J'aurais préféré une construction plus directe, mais c'est une question de style.

Answer (score 0):

La préposition « de » est la préposition habituelle utilisée après le verbe décider lorsque il a le sens de « prendre une décision à propos de quelque chose ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cider)) **décider de**
> **II**.− Emploi trans. indir.
> **A.** − [Le suj. désigne une pers.]
> **1** . Décider de + subst. Arbitrer, déterminer, juger.

Cependant, le sujet ne peut pas être une chose (seulement une personne), et dans la proposition donnée le sujet est manquant, d'où une erreur.

- afin que soit décidé de [cette réponse] (coi) (*Il s'agit d'un passif.*)

Il y a une méprise du coi avec un sujet inversé ; dans la phrase suivante ce n'est pas le cas, mais il s'agit du sens suivant.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cider)) A.− Juger un point contesté, opter pour une conclusion définitive qui tranche, après délibération, un litige.

- … afin que soit décidée [cette question] (sujet) (*syntaxe correcte*)
- … afin que cette question soit décidée (*syntaxe toujours correcte, sujet placé normalement*)

Il semble exister la possibilité d'utiliser le sujet impersonnel « il » ; on trouve quelques exemples, mais des phrases telles que la suivantes ne sont pas très usuelles de nos jours.

- Il est peu probable qu'il soit parlé de mythologie dans cette classe.

([Rapport annuel 2014 du Fonds monétaire international](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rapport_annuel_2014_du_Fonds_mon%C3%A9taire/xT8ZEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&pg=PA60&printsec=frontcover)) Aux termes de cette décision, la distribution n'interviendra que lorsque les pays montant des bénéfices exceptionnels, étant versé à la réserve générale en attendant qu'il soit décidé de son affectation définitive.

([Décisions et rapports 15 Commission européenne des Droits de](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/D%C3%A9cisions_et_rapports_15_Commission_eur/28auUJXixsAC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover)) à un droit civil au sens que cette expression reçoit dans la Convention , il découle de l'article 6 que les requérantes ont un droit d'accès aux tribunaux pour qu'il soit décidé de ce droit civil dans un délai raisonnable .

([Rapport annuel 2013: Promouvoir une économie mondiale plus](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rapport_annuel_2013/NbUZEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&pg=PA58&printsec=frontcover)) de 2,45 milliards de DTS, soit le montant de bénéfices exceptionnels, étant versé à la réserve générale en at- tendant qu'il soit décidé de son affectation finale.

([International Review of Criminal Policy](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/International_Review_of_Criminal_Policy/r8QwocBcarMC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover)) Si on l'estime nécessaire on peut toutefois présenter au tribunal d'exécution des peines , au cours de chaque période , une nouvelle proposition afin qu'il soit décidé de la destination à donner au détenu.

([Histoire de l'Organization de l'armée secrète](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Histoire_de_l_Organization_de_l_arm%C3%A9e_s/rBE-AAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover)) Donc, les professeurs du lycée Gauthier sont conduits au centre d'internement de Beni-Messous , en attendant qu'il soit décidé de leur sort !

([De la pacification à la répression: le dossier Jean Muller](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/De_la_pacification_%C3%A0_la_r%C3%A9pression/h5MvAAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&dq=%22soit+d%C3%A9cid%C3%A9+de%22&printsec=frontcover)) Ils y séjournent plus ou moins longuement, en attendant qu'il soit décidé de leur sort.

Donc, la phrase suivante serait acceptable.

- Vous avez été 139 États à me demander d’organiser cette session extraordinaire avant juillet, afin qu'*il* soit décidé de cette réponse.

Néanmoins, le passif avec un sujet impersonnel qui s'insinue lorsqu'un sujet défini ne peut pas être nommé, se traduit beaucoup mieux par la voix active et le pronom sujet indéfini « on ».

- Vous avez été 139 États à me demander d’organiser cette session extraordinaire avant juillet, afin que *l'on* décide de cette réponse. (*Note :* "afin qu'on décide" *est correct, mais reste considéré par certaines personnes comme pas très élégant.*)

Comment: -1 parce que le sujet de _décider_ peut être une chose, et n'a pas besoin d'être une personne dans tous les cas: _la météo décidera de l'heure d'arrivée_.

Comment: Ben justement... l'article du TLFi est plein d'examples où le verbe _décider_ (il n'y en a qu'un, une seule page de TLFi, avec plusieurs _emplois_), avec _de_, a un sujet inanimé...  TLFi donne par example: _Le dénouement qui doit décider de sa destinée [au peuple] (Clemenceau, L'Iniquité,1899, p. VII)._ Ou encore: _La faim, qui décide aux migrations les espèces voyageuses (Michelet, Oiseau,1856, p. 140)_, et encore une fois, la page du TLFi est remplie d'autres examples...

Comment: @Frank Il est question d'un autre sens de « décider » ; il ne s'agit pas de débat mais de circonstances ; vous vous trompez de verbe : dans la session, ce ne sont pas des circonstances qui vont en fin de compte déterminer quoi que ce soit.

Comment: Il est question ... d'un autre _sens_ du verbe décider, ou d'un autre _verbe_ (d'après vous)? "Vous avez été 139 États à me demander d’organiser cette session extraordinaire avant juillet, _et cette session décidera de notre réponse_". Aucun problème.

Comment: @Frank On est très loin dans la phrase originale de dire que c'est la session, et il est clair qu'une session c'est une rencontre qui vise essentiellement à la discussion.  Le tour que vous essayez de donner à la phrase n'est pas naturel. De plus, il s'agit soit de l'une ou de l'autre des deux acceptions, et donc pour vous c'est la « B » et on doit considérer la « A » comme non applicable ? Faites comme vous voulez, mais je vais maintenir ma réponse telle quelle.

Comment: Pas naturel? Une recherche très rapide sur google trouve: _L'Assemblée générale décide du thème de la session 2024 de l'ECOSOC et du forum politique de haut niveau pour le développement durable._, par exemple.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas ici d'une inversion du sujet (décision) - verbe (décidé de) ?

Comment: @AlexW Non, dans la construction qui vous concerne, il n'y a pas d'inversion du sujet, en fait le sujet manque. Je parle de cas d'inversion pour expliquer comment dans l'esprit du scripteur ces constructions où il y a une inversion peuvent rendre la syntaxe ambigüe si on ne fait pas attention ou si on n'a pas encore assez d'expérience. Il est quand même assez bizarre que cette clause ne comporte pas de sujet, c'est bien une erreur.

Comment: Je vous remercie !